# R join large data table with Vector and repeat X times

Tags: r, left-join, data.table

I am a newbie to R and trying to work through a challenge...

I have two data tables in R that I want to join together, but also repeat one of the tables (table 2) multiple times. The format of the tables is as below.

```
Table 1 (7500+ rows by 665 Columns each row is unique)
num_Hrs  Column A   Column B .... Column XZ
3128_1     0           1              0
3128_2     1           0              1
3128_3     1           0              1

Table 2 (each row is unique)
ColumnData
12345
12346
12347
12348
```

How can I join the two tables and repeat the 25 rows from table 2 to each row in table 1 so I end up with 7500 * 25 rows with the ColumnData appended? I don't want to touch any row in Table 1 only add 1 new column with the values in Table 2 repeated (duplicating rows).

```
TableMain
num_Hrs  Column A   Column B .... Column XZ ColumnData
3128_1     0           1              0         12345
3128_1     0           1              0         12346
3128_1     0           1              0         12347 
3128_2     1           1              0         12345
3128_2     1           1              0         12346
3128_2     1           1              0         12347
```

I then need to take the resulting TableMain and add a new Column where I have table 3 that has matching values to num_Hrs in table 1 and Column Data in table 2.

```
Table 3
num_hrs   ColumnData
3128_1     1234
3128_1     1235
3128_2     1234
```

And if those two values match values in the TableMain put a 1 in a new column called "Found"

```
num_Hrs  Column A   Column B .... Column XZ ColumnData Found
3128_1     0           1              0         12345   1
3128_1     0           1              0         12346   0
3128_1     0           1              0         12347   1
3128_2     1           1              0         12345   0
3128_2     1           1              0         12346   0
3128_2     1           1              0         12347   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
dt1 = data.table(a = 1:4, b = 4:1)
#   a b
#1: 1 4
#2: 2 3
#3: 3 2
#4: 4 1

dt2 = data.table(c = letters[1:4])
#   c
#1: a
#2: b
#3: c
#4: d

dt2[, dt1[], by = c]
#    c a b
# 1: a 1 4
# 2: a 2 3
# 3: a 3 2
# 4: a 4 1
# 5: b 1 4
# 6: b 2 3
# 7: b 3 2
# 8: b 4 1
# 9: c 1 4
#10: c 2 3
#11: c 3 2
#12: c 4 1
#13: d 1 4
#14: d 2 3
#15: d 3 2
#16: d 4 1

dt3 = data.table(a = c(2, 4, 4), c = c('c', 'a', 'd'))
#   a c
#1: 2 c
#2: 4 a
#3: 4 d

dt2[, dt1[], by = c][, found := 0][dt3, found := 1, on = c('a', 'c')][]
#    c a b found
# 1: a 1 4     0
# 2: a 2 3     0
# 3: a 3 2     0
# 4: a 4 1     1
# 5: b 1 4     0
# 6: b 2 3     0
# 7: b 3 2     0
# 8: b 4 1     0
# 9: c 1 4     0
#10: c 2 3     1
#11: c 3 2     0
#12: c 4 1     0
#13: d 1 4     0
#14: d 2 3     0
#15: d 3 2     0
#16: d 4 1     1
```

One note - there is some sort of a weird bug in `data.table` that doesn't let me simply do `dt2[, dt1, by = c]`.

Comment: eddi, this is pretty awesome. This first part works but I don't understand how the final step works. It looks like is saying on=c('a','c') based on values in column C? or is it by the column header?

Comment: nevermind I figured it out. My column names were off by an "S". Thanks so much for the help!!!

Comment: Why is this freezing? Or am I just not waiting long enough?

Comment: @zsad512 What's "this"? The code in answer works fine for me.